# Same this.setState function called simultaneously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a problem that setState being called simultaneously by various children components

Here is some oversimplificated code:

```js
var Content = React.createClass({
  updateElements: function(element) {
    elements = [].concat(this.state.elements)
    elements.push(element)
    this.setState({ elements })
  }

  render: function() {
    elements = ["a", "b"];

    return (
      <div>
        <Element updateElements={this.updateElements} data={elements[0]} />
        <Element updateElements={this.updateElements} data={elements[1]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Element = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
     this.props.updateElements(this.props.data)
  }

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
         {this.props.data}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Content />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Can I somehow wait for the previous state to be set before updating it once again?

Comment: Have you read the docs for [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)? You can pass it a function if you want to update based on the previous state. That will stop it from mattering which order the updates run in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `setState` [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> This form of setState() is also asynchronous, and multiple calls
>   during the same cycle may be batched together

Which means assuming you have 2 child elements that call the following parent method:

```
  doSomething1(amount){
    this.setState({
      sum1: this.state.sum1 + amount
    }, () => {
      console.warn(this.state.sum1); // 1
    })
  }
```

Both will log 1, because subsequent calls will override values from previous calls in the same cycle, so the quantity will only be incremented once.

Instead you should use the updater function form:

```
  doSomething2(amount) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { sum2: prevState.sum2 + amount };
    }, () => {
      console.warn(this.state.sum2); // 2
    });
  }
```

[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n00mvvnop4)

This can solve your problem if your issue is depending on the previous value of the state.

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure but this should work.If you do setState like this

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {elements: [...prevState.elements, element]};
});
```

It won't be synchronous but it should persists the element without overiding it(because of simultaneous update) as it will be taking from prevState.